# Are there free datasets available with several tables?

Tags: data-request

I want to make a presentation with comparison of pandas and pyspark. For this purpose I need some data and ideally a research task that will allow me to:

1. Show how joins works in both libraries. So at least the data should consist of two datasets. Ideally data should allow and the task should require some joins/group bys to be performed to show all the spark sql features.
2. Compare the speed of the libs.
3. Ideally data should come with a research task/tutorial, so I could show PySpark mllib in action

Could someone please suggest a tutorial/kaggle page/anything that will fit my requirements?

Comment: You probably know https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/  in particular [comparison_with_sql.html#join](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#join) . Also there's https://github.com/spark-examples/pyspark-examples